Typescript: Incompatible types with spread syntax inside index signature
Given this example:
type Foo = {
  [key: string]: {
    bar: "bar",
    baz: string[],
    qux: string,
  };
}

const obj = {
  bar: "bar",
  baz: ["baz"],
};

const a: Foo = {
  key: { // error TS2322: Type '{ bar: string; baz: string[]; qux: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ bar: "bar"; baz: string[]; qux: string; }'.
    qux: "qux",
    ...obj,
  },
};

console.log(a);

How can I avoid this error while staying strongly typed? I tried adding as const to partial, but that then it runs into this error:
The type 'readonly ["baz"]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'string[]'.


If you hover over obj you can see the inferred type is bar: string. One way to fix it is to tell Typescript the type of obj as in const obj:{bar: "bar", baz:string[]} = {...}

You can also do bar: "bar" as const, or if you make the whole object as const you could make baz: readonly string[], in the Foo type

Use as const only on the key bar instead of the whole object.
type Foo = {
  [key: string]: {
    bar: "bar",
    baz: string[],
    qux: string,
  };
}

const obj = {
  bar: "bar" as const, // <-- HERE
  baz: ["baz"],
} // as const; <-- NOT HERE

const a: Foo = {
  key: { 
    qux: "qux",
    ...obj,
  },
};

console.log(a);

TS Playground

you can use satisfies if using typescript > 5. Where if you were to write
const a = 'hi' as const satisfies string

the type of a is hi. But writing
const a = 4 as const satisfies string

will give you an error type 'number' does not satisfy the expected type 'string'.
So for your example could be
const obj = {
  bar: "bar",
  baz: ["baz"],
} satisfies Partial<Foo[string]>;

If you don't want to use satisfies or are using an older typescript version you can use a generic function to create the partial object.
const createObj = <T extends Partial<Foo[string]>>(obj:T)=>obj;

This just ensures the type of the argument satisfied the generic, and consequentially the return type of the function, the output variable also satisfies the generic.

The problem with current implementation is that the type of obj is inferred as
const obj: {
    bar: string;
    baz: string[];
}

but foo expects these types for the values:
    bar: "bar",
    baz: string[],

So we want the type of bar to be narrowed (be as specific as possible) and type of baz to stay as is.
This can be achieved in a few ways:

Using const asssertion (on the specific field):

const obj = {
    bar: "bar" as const,
  baz: ["baz"],
};


Defining the type of obj with readonly:

const obj : {
    readonly bar : "bar",
    baz: string[]
}= {
    bar: "bar",
  baz: ["baz"],
};

Playground : Remove the comments to see different implementations

I think you want to do something like this to split the assigns:
type bee = {
  bar: "bar";
  baz: string[];
};
type Foo = {
  [key: string]: bee & { qux: string };
};

const obj: bee = {
  bar: "bar",
  baz: ["baz"],
};

const a: Foo = {
  key: {
    // error TS2322: Type '{ bar: string; baz: string[]; qux: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ bar: "bar"; baz: string[]; qux: string; }'.
    qux: "qux",
    ...obj,
  },
};

